# Is it possible for a function to automatically cast an object if it passes

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Suppose I have an object that can be two different classes in a scenario like

```
const obj: A | B = ...
        
if ( isClassA(obj) ) {
    // obj = <A> obj
    ...
} else {
    // obj = <B> obj
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to automactically cast obj to its appropriate class based on the result of isClassA()?

Comment: What is `isClassA`s return type?

Comment: In this case it's boolean, but other solutions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a [Type Predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)?

[Example on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuoksiKAQprgcgEYnmUQNHPRy4wATwAOKVAHsoHALxpkAH2RsA3AxwI5Icsjk8AViXmLkKjIRIAiABIQANi7n3ktQqTQLtXNwEjDDIABTIwKQAwi5wpKSoYSamAJTI6dh4BPqGci4QAHTuVMlmhXCpOiLIrqQoWdy5pPlFJWWmhTxVdLrIAPT9mnJgABbGoWMQ9cjwwC5EuM2txXKlKRU9egYtBavr5d3VuDAAriAIYMAGkTFxCUkpJHAgEqkkKbeqjQRQEGCnKAgYzlODIACEShU5wAJhAYKAIDDqrQgA)

```
function isClassA(obj: any): obj is A {
    return /* your implementation */;
}
```